# How to handle failed inserted data into a cloud server due to poor Internet connectivity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, amazon-web-services, job-scheduling, data-entry

Is there an elegant way to handle failed inserted data into a cloud server from an input box due to poor Internet connectivity? The users' location can have a poor Internet connection for weeks/months. I'm creating a Rails web application where multiple clients continuously (every 1-2 seconds) enter data into an input box and no entry can be missed. It is critical that every entry gets inserted into the cloud in the exact order it was entered. I'm thinking instead of having the input box directly insert into the cloud database (AWS RDS / Amazon DynamoDB) after each entry, the data would be inserted into a local table and a separate job would insert the data into the cloud and continue to re-try until all the data have been inserted. Here's what I'm thinking -

[handle failed input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRvsY.png)

I've been searching for a solution and this is the closest I've seen - https://github.com/chanks/que .I'm looking for guidance on best practices or already implemented and tested solutions (don't want to re-invent the wheel). Thanks in advance and appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of a situation, design your application as an **Offline-First** web application. This will allow,

- Your application to write to an offline storage with the input timestamp.
- Another piece of code, synchronizes your data with the backend service periodically looking at network availability.

In AWS, instead of implementing your own core logic for synchronization you can use [AWS Cognito Sync](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-sync.html) Storage.

- You can write JavaScript code using [AWS SDK for Cognito](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoSync.html) to write to the Local Cognito Storage (Here each user will get its own storage).
- The SDK will make sure to persist it and synchronize it with the backend service when the network availability is there.
- In your backend, you can trigger a Lambda function upon data retrieval to store it to storage like DynamoDB for shared operations.

Note: If you are expecting very large number of inputs per second (e.g 1000 >) and you plan to do operations on input as batches, you can stream the changes received by the backend service to [AWS Kineses Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/).

In addition, there are other options such as using [Pouch DB for Offline First Web Applications](https://stories.jotform.com/offline-first-web-applications-d2d321444510) which has a JS storage component that can synchronize the data with the Pouch DB Server.

Comment: I don't think users are actually manually inputting every 1-2 seconds - I would guess that it is some sort of microcontroller that probally does not use a browser. Otherwise its a well thought out answer.

Comment: @max - you've guessed right. It's not an actual "user" but is a form of a microcontroller, barcode scanners to be exact. A barcode would reach the first scanning station "User 1" and scan the barcode into the input field. There will be a computer at the station with a browser open and cursor auto-focused to the input field specific for that station. Ashan recommended Pouch DB could be the solution and something I would need to look at it if my simpler approach from the diagram I added previously is not feasible. Is there a simpler approach for Ruby on Rails?